# How to get relocated base address in PE Files?

Tags: windows, portable-executable

I'm trying to make Simple PE Packer. My PE Viewer show me base address `0x40000000`, but OllyDbg show me `0x01900400` or other address.

I guess that it is address relocation.

1. how to get relocated address ?
2. what do make packer simple sequence ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A PE file has a preferred base address. If you're writing a PE Viewer, then it sounds like it will analyze the PE file only. This is a static analysis, so you'll only get the preferred base address, which is `0x40000000`.

OllyDbg is a debugger, which is a totally different thing than a PE Viewer. A debugger performs a dynamic analysis at runtime. At runtime, the PE file might have been loaded to a different address, since the preferred address was already used.

So, in my opinion, your PE Viewer program does what it should do - except if you wanted to write a debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Thomas has already explained that base address is just a preferred address, it does not guarantee you that file will load on that address only.
Still, in most of the cases, it should be 400000. If you are using Windows XP, this condition is satisfied most of the times. But from Windows Vista and Windows 7, a new concept known as ASLR was introduced. 
When you see some other address while the file is loaded in debugger, it is because of  ASLR(Address Space Randomization).

What is ASLR? 
Address Space Layout Randomization calculates the address of PE files in memory based on the processor's timestamp counter.
Formula = ([SHR4(Timestamp Counter) mod 254] + 1)*64KB
**need confirmation for formula

Why ASLR?
The main motto behind ASL was to stop malware authors from using various flaws of memory structures like buffer overflow, etc. The randomly arranged memory structures and modules made the guessing of memory addresses(where they wished to put malicious code) difficult for them.

Now, coming back to your question: How to get relocated address:
If you can find the CPU timestamp, which I doubt is possible, you can calculate the base location of executable.[How to bypass ASLR](https://www.abatchy.com/2017/06/exploit-dev-101-bypassing-aslr-on.html)

Otherwise, you cannot retrieve this address(for Windows Vista and above) after ASLR from a PE file structure.

Also, you can refer to this:
https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/18556/how-do-aslr-and-dep-work